# Bash + замена с регулярным выражением

Tags: linux, bash

Есть текстовый файл, который надо изменить по шаблону, например

```
 [(].*$|^.*-
```

(в начале и конце пробелы).
Я могу им в LibreOffice заменить, но хотелось бы делать это просто запуская bash-скрипт.
Как бы мне это сделать?

Совсем забыл - найденные подстроки удаляются, т.е. меняются на ничего.

Благодарен человеку, который отписал про sed, жаль что удалили комментарий! Правда пока не понял, почему он мне пишет в консоль, а не в файл, но наверное есть и такая функция, найду)
Нашел!

Comment: в любой реализации posix-оболочки (в т.ч. и интерпретаторе bash) весьма громоздко и затруднительно оперировать с регулярными выражениями. есть более приспособленные для этого интерпретаторы, входящие в posix-совместимые операционные системы: ed, sed, awk.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i s/' [\(].*$\|^.*- '/''/ <файл>
```